# My CHAR to BINARY conversion into a ARRAY does not work

Tags: arrays, c, binary

i had write a program, that convert a char to binary code... All were working when i had that code

```
int n, c, k;
n = character;
for (c = 7; c >= 0; c--)
  {
    k = n >> c;
 if (k & 1)
     printf("1");
    else
      printf("0");
}
```

But I must to write these values to an **ARRAY** and I edited code like u can see below and thats not worked.. Can you help me please?

```
void encode_char(const char character, bool bits[8]) {
int n, c, k;
n = character;
  for (c = 7; c >= 0; c--)
  {
    k = n >> c;

    if (k & 1)
      bits[c] = "1";
    else
      bits[c] = "0";
  }

  printf("\n");
}
```

[image: Arena code]
In a Arena (that controls the program) you can see error: *Assertion 'encode_char('r', bits) => {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}' failed. [got {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}]]*

Comment: The characters `'0'` and `'1'` are both `true` (any non-0 value is `true`). Try `0` and `1` instead of the characters.

Comment: replace "if (k & 1)
      bits[c] = "1";
    else
      bits[c] = "0";"
with 
"bits[c] = k & 1;"

Comment: I suggest listening to compiler's warnings: at `bits[c] = "1";` the compiler should complain because you are assigning a `const cahr *` to a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible implementation for the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void encode_char(char character, bool bits[8]) {
    for (int bit_index = 7; bit_index >= 0; bit_index--, character >>= 1)
        bits[bit_index] = character & 1;
}

int main() {
    bool bits[8];
    encode_char('U', bits);

    for (int bit_index = 0; bit_index < 8; bit_index++)
        printf("%d", bits[bit_index]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Some points:

- You don't need so many variables for the bits extraction logic, you're already creating a new variable in the function, so just change its value.
- Like the comments stated, you're comparing a bit and not a byte.

Comment: I just must created variable n, n=character, because of character must be const, but otherwise it works. Thanks.